# Do any web graphing or charting libraries have support for error bars?

Tags: web-applications, charts, graph, google-visualization

I have been looking for a graphing library to use in an upcoming web application, but I have two requirements that have been tripping me up:

1. Ability to save the graph as an image.
2. Show error bars on the points of line charts as well as bar charts.

I have found solutions to #1 by using flash charts or even the Google Chart API. However requirement #2 has completely stopped me dead in my tracks, it seems like all existing frameworks leave out this functionality entirely.

I have tried out quite a few libraries already, including:

- [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/)

  - It seems like they only have the ability to put markers on points with their Chart API. This involves only static images. No interactivity. Also their error bar marker can only be drawn spanning between two series, rather than extending on either direction in the y-axis off a single data point.
- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

  - Great looking javascript graphs - No support for error bars as far as I can tell.
- [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com)

  - I thought I had found my solution [here](http://www.amcharts.com/xy/error-bars/) but it really is just a hacked bubble chart where the bubbles look like error bars, and there appears to be no functionality for drawing error bars on a bar graph.

I would prefer javascript graphs but I am willing to settle for flash. Has anyone come across this issue before? Are there any existing javascript or flash graphing libraries that support error bars? This seems like it would be a highly requested feature for any semi-scientific web application.

Comment: Have you looked at gRaphael? Im thinking it may be trivial to modify any existing graphs to add your own functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can find these useful:

http://www.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/charts/error-bar/

http://dygraphs.com/

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/error.html

I think you export a image of the chart with fusioncharts.